# Can I create class properties during __new__ or __init__?

Tags: python

I want to do something like this, but I haven't had much success so far.  I would like to make each attr a property that computes _lazy_eval only when accessed:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for attr in self._myattrs:
            setattr(self, attr, property(lambda self: self._lazy_eval(attr)))

    def _lazy_eval(self, attr):
        #Do complex stuff here
        return attr


class Child(Base):
    _myattrs = ['foo', 'bar']


me = Child()
print me.foo
print me.bar

#desired output:
#"foo"
#"bar"
```

** UPDATE **

This doesn't work either:

```
class Base(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        for attr in cls._myattrs:
            setattr(cls, attr, property(lambda self: self._lazy_eval(attr)))
        return object.__new__(cls)

#Actual output (it sets both .foo and .bar equal to "bar"??)
#bar
#bar
```

** UPDATE 2 **

Used the `__metaclass__` solution, but stuck it in `Base.__new__` instead.  It looks like it needed a better defined closure -- "prop()" -- to form the property correctly:

```
class Base(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        def prop(x):
            return property(lambda self: self._lazy_eval(x))
        for attr in cls._myattrs:
            setattr(cls, attr, prop(attr))
        return object.__new__(cls)

#Actual output!  It works!
#foo
#bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you want a metaclass:

```
class LazyMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        super(LazyMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, attr)
        def prop( x ):
            return property(lambda self: self._lazy_eval(x))
        for x in attr['lazyattrs']:
            setattr(cls, x, prop(x))

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = LazyMeta
    lazyattrs = []
    def _lazy_eval(self, attr):
        #Do complex stuff here
        return attr

class Child(Base):
    lazyattrs = ['foo', 'bar']

me = Child()

print me.foo
print me.bar
```

Answer (score 5):

Descriptors (such as instances of the `property` type) are only meaningful when they're held in the *class* object, not the *instance* object.  So, you need to change the class, not the instance, and (in Python 2.6 or better) a class decorator is very handy for that purpose:

```
class Base(object):
    def _lazy_eval(self, attr):
        #Do complex stuff here
        return attr

def lazyclass(cls):
    for attr in cls._myattrs:
        setattr(cls, attr, property(lambda self: self._lazy_eval(attr)))
    return cls

@lazyclass
class Child(Base):
    _myattrs = ['foo', 'bar']
```

If you're stuck with Python 2.5 or earlier, the decorator syntax doesn't apply to classes, but it's easy to get the same effect, just with less nifty syntax -- change the last 3 rows to:

```
class Child(Base):
    _myattrs = ['foo', 'bar']
Child = lazyclass(Child)
```

which has the same semantics as the class decorator syntax.

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  Unfortunately, this decorator method doesn't work for me.  It gives me the same results as the __new__ method (see my update to the question above).

Answer (score 1):

You can access class attributes through the __ class __ dict

```
self.__class__.attr
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `__getattr__()` instead:

```
class Base(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr not in self._myattrs:
            raise AttributeError
        return self._lazy_eval(attr)

    def _lazy_eval(self, attr):
        #Do complex stuff here
        return attr


class Child(Base):
    _myattrs = ['foo', 'bar']

me = Child()
print me.foo
print me.bar
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works.  It feels a little less elegant, but it may be the best solution.